# Passing Dynamic dictionary argument to Operator in Airflow based on user input

Tags: python, airflow

Hey so i've been trying to figure out a way to modify and pass a dictionary argument to my operator based on the inputs I am getting from the tasks above. example the "cluster" here is a dictionary argument loaded before the dag is initialized

```
run = CustomOperator(
            task_id='task',
            new_cluster=cluster,
            ...,
```

here 'cluster' is a dictionary value. modifying it in a task and returning it, I'll have to use xcom which returns a string even when I do a "{{(xcom)|tojson }}" I'm getting the value in single quotes and not a dict.

IF I modify the preloaded dictionary right before the operator as shown below, it works but only if the modification is static. But I want the modified value to be the one I choose from a file based on the input to the dag from dagRun.conf or a previous task return value{{xcom_pull}} it throws an error in compiling the DAG saying BROKEN DAG: '{{dagRun.conf}}':

```
cluster['value a'] = file_change["{{dag_run.conf}}"]
run = CustomOperator(
            task_id='task',
            new_cluster=cluster,
            ...,
```

I could work even if I could call a function that returns back the dict to get the argument :

```
def modify(cluster):
....
...
..

with dag:
run = CustomOperator(
            task_id='task',
            new_cluster=modify(cluster),
            ...
```

early help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that the `models.DAG` object (*the `dag = DAG(...)` result*): is constructed/initialized *when the file with the process is loaded* -- not when the subsequent object is executed in the context of a run. You can't access anything related to the run because none exists yet.

> I think you're on the right path regarding pass it through XCom, depending on size and if it can be done some other way, but I think you're also trying to use it as a templated field when it's not -- update your question with code for more details please.

Comment: Hey, @joeb  yup that's what i feel... Can you suggest another way of getting xcom as an argument in the operator apart from template? Because i could only use "{{ti.xcom}}" in that place

Comment: hey @joeb the custom operator i'm using is by someone else, so I cannot modify it.
at the same time the  xcom is only available in template form I assume if we use it as an argument to the operator. could you please suggest another way?